# Using self/this in scala super/constructor call

Tags: scala

I need to pass a reference to the current object (the one being created) to the constructor being called.

```
class Example(
  val test: String,
  var origin: Example
) {
  def this(test: String) {
    this(test, this)
  }
}
```

But I the compiler complains "this can be used only in a class, object, or template".

If I remember right, this was a no opt in Java, so I'm sure it's possible. But how should I write it ?

Comment: I think you should reconsider having it in the constructor. Rethink why you're doing it that way and think of a different way of doing it that might fit Scala better?

Comment: Yes I did change my way of doing it. I'm just amazed it's not possible to write this in Scala.

Comment: I can't think of a moment when I've ever would've needed it in Scala and I worked with it for a year now. You get used to doing things differently. Even now I don't understand why you want to use it like that. Really, I'm just as amazed over why you'd need to do that